# How to find other elements using xpath using one element

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

Hi I have a html page like below:

```
<tr>
    <td class = "sdfgg" >
     <nobr> 3000 </nobr>
    </td>
    <td class = "retre" >
    <nobr> Comm error </nobr>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class ="fdhdf" >
    <nobr> Time: </nobr>
    </td>
    <td class ="csfds" >
    <nobr> 10:00PM </nobr>
    </td>
    <td class ="hdfh" >
    <nobr> Data code: </nobr>
    </td>
    <td class ="dfhfd" >
    <nobr> 456 </nobr>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to find all other elements using element "3000" which is event id.
I find this element as follows:

`$"//nobr[text()='{eventId}']"`  which is nothing but  `$"//nobr[text()='3000']"`

I can also find Comm error by using event id in xpath as below:

```
$"//td/nobr[text()='{eventID}']/parent::td/following-sibling::td/nobr"
```

How do I find remaining elements using the same event id?. Could someone please help? Other elements to find using '3000' are: "Time", "10:00 PM" , "Data code", "456" 
The page being dynamic i cannot use class attribute.

Comment: `//nobr[contains(text(),' 3000 ')]`

Comment: No, it doesn't work .. It is same as $"//nobr[text()='3000']" .It gives element 3000 alone

Comment: `//td/nobr[text()='{eventID}']/parent::td/following-sibling::td//nobr`

Comment: What about `//td/nobr[text()='3000']/following::nobr` ?

Comment: Hi Narendra, Thanks. But no luck!

Comment: Any things to share, any error if space causing isssue then trim using `//td/nobr[normalize-space()='3000']/following::nobr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following x-paths may help you.

To find the element comm error

```
//td/nobr[normalize-space(text())='3000']/parent::td/following-sibling::td/nobr
```

To find other elements

```
//td/nobr[normalize-space(text())='3000']/../../following-sibling::tr[1]/td/nobr
```

Comment: Wow. It worked perfectly..!! you also solved the white space problem. You are awesome. Thanks!